# VBA when error 9 occurs do not show error message

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a quick question, and the solutions found here didnt work and were 6 years old.

ik have a little vba code that links to another page of the workbook where it gets the page name from another cell.

```
Sub link()

    Sheets(Range("L7").Value).Activate
    Range("J3").Select

End Sub
```

It works like a charm, only if the page it wants to link to does not exist i get an error 9 because it wants to link to something that isn't there. Is there any way to remove the error and if it triggers just doesnt do anything?

Comment: `On Error` look at error handling in VBA.

Comment: If you are dealing with multiple sheets, you should probably avoid things like `Range("L7").Value` and instead use things like `Sheets(1).Range("L7").Value`. Also, it seems that you might benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248).